# Why does my implementation of get / set give a stack error?

Tags: c#

I am trying the following in C#:

```
public class Reference : AuditableTable
    {
        [Range(0, 99, ErrorMessage = "{0} must be between {1} and {2}")]
        [DisplayName("Order")]
        public int Order {
                get { return Order; }
                set {
                    if ((value < 0) || (value > 99)) {
                        throw new Exception(string.Format("{0} must be between 0 and 99", value.ToString()));
                    } else {
                        Order = value;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Can someone help explain why this would give a stack overflow error when reading?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your property is referencing itself, thus resulting in an infinite loop.

An obvious fix is to use a private field and expose it through your property:

```
private int order;
public int Order
{
   get
   {
      return order; //private field
   }
   set
   {
      if ((value < 0) || (value > 99)) {
               throw new Exception(string.Format("{0} must be between 0 and 99",    
                                     value.ToString()));
      } else {
          order = value; // again accessing the private field (setting this time)
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is this line:

```
get { return Order; }
```

This is calling the property recursively, which results in a stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Both the setter and getter are referencing themselves causing the Stack Overflow. Fix it like this:

```
private int _order;

public int Order {
    get { return _order; }
    set {
        if ((value < 0) || (value > 99)) {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("{0} must be between 0 and 99", value.ToString()));
        } else {
            _order = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int _order;
public int Order {
    get { return _order; }
    set {
        if ((value < 0) || (value > 99)) {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("{0} must be between 0 and 99", value.ToString()));
        } else {
            _order = value;
        }
    }
}
```